# gnome-keyring interfering with gcloud ssh & copy-files

Tags: ssh, gcloud, gnome-keyring-daemon

---- this question has been cross-posted on ----
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-cloud-sdk/voxZDVSD6Bg

Greetings

When I attempt to use "gcloud compute ssh" or "gcloud compute copy-files", a dialogue box pops-up and says:

---

"Enter password to unlock the private key
An application wants to access the private key 'trashmob@superminion', but it is locked"

---

(This happens, for example using
gcloud compute ssh uncleanspirit_gmail_com@instance-1 --zone us-central1-f --project corpse-marionette-851)

Alas, no password I supply will placate it.  It does not seem to help if I've logged into to an account on my local computer with admin privileges or not.  I do this after "gcloud auth login".  I am using ubuntu 14.04.  I have no trouble to SSH to the instance using the web interface.

This likely has to do with gnome-keyring, not gcloud.  A lot of us use linux distributions which use gnome, and gnome no longer makes it easy to disable (the ssh agent) in gnome-keyring.  Anyone know how to get around this snag?

Thank you in advance

Andrew
P.S. This may also be relevant:
gcloud uses ECDSA, and gnome-keyring does not yet fully support ECDSA (ed25519?)
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641082

Comment: Do you know what key it's prompting you about? Is this the key that you're supposed to use to connect to that host? Is this key protected with a passphrase? Do you know the passphrase?

Comment: From searching around on google, I think it is asking for the user password on my local machine.  (And that user must have admin privileges.)  I can confirm that none of these issues occur when using kubuntu 14.10 (a version of ubuntu using the KDE window environment).  ssh and copy-files work great.  My advice to other users with this problem is to change their window environment, or make a USB boot disk, and use it to run gcloud.

Comment: If it helps, in both cases: I installed "gcloud" in ubuntu by adding the "http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu partner" repository and installed using "sudo apt-get update", and "sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk")

Comment: After further investigation: The problem does not occur on a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.
    However it is not necessary to replace the window manager either.  If anyone else runs into this problem, I was finally able to get
gcloud ssh working on the original problematic OS:
1) I deleted these two directories: ~/.local/share/keyrings   and  ~/.ssh
  (Perhaps deleting .ssh was unnecessary.)
2) I logged out of my local computer.
     (This step seems to be important.)
3) Then I logged in again.
4) Then I attempted to connect with "gcloud auth login" and "gcloud
compute ssh".

Comment: (Incidentally, it took me several iterations of steps 1-4 to get everything working.  I had to do this for each user account on my local machine.)